# How to make custom theme using Shoutem's StyleProvider that properly uses underlying INCLUDE

Tags: reactjs, react-native, shoutem

I really love the shoutem theme library, but I'm finding it difficult to hook into the recursive INCLUDE that makes the underlying code work beautifully (See code+documentation here: https://github.com/shoutem/theme/blob/develop/src/Theme.js). For instance, if we have:

```
render() {
    return (
        <StyleProvider style={theme}>
            <View />
        </StyleProvider>
    );
}

const theme = _.merge(getTheme(), {
    'shoutem.ui.Text': {
        color: 'green',
    },
});
```

This simple text color change will work, but **only** for shoutem Text components. However, Heading, Title, Subtitle, etc. all of which pull from Text attributes in the shoutem library because of INCLUDE. The use of a simple _.merge(...) only overwrites the component itself, but not anything that it might subsequently affects. It sounds like I need to overwrite attributes higher up in the tree (e.g., Text), and then regenerate the theme so it affects all "children" that it's included in (e.g., Heading and Title). Using the publicly exposed API, is this possible to do somehow at the moment? Or are there any forks or utilities you're aware of that accomplish this with your library.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `text` property in the root of the default shoutem ui theme that is included into all text elements (https://github.com/shoutem/ui/blob/develop/theme.js#L292). You should be able to accomplish your use case by simply overriding values from that property:

```
const theme = _.merge(getTheme(), {
  text: {
    color: 'green',
  },
});
```

In case you want to create a more complex theme, you can use `INCLUDE` in your code as well. `INCLUDE` works by merging all values from top level theme properties it targets. You can use it to include properties from the base theme, and you can also include your own custom properties:

```
import { INCLUDE } from '@shoutem/theme';

const theme = _.merge(getTheme(), {
  // Define a top level property to use in includes
  largeText: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  'shoutem.ui.Text': {
    // Include a text property from the base theme
    // and a largeText property defined above
    [INCLUDE]: ['text', 'largeText'],

    // Override the text color after all includes
    // have been resolved
    color: 'green',
  },
});
```

Sometimes specific components define styles after INCLUDEs have been resolved, those styles have a higher priority, and will always override the style from INCLUDEs. To change those styles, you can use a `createSharedStyle` helper:

```
import { createSharedStyle } from '@shoutem/theme';

const textComponents = [
  'shoutem.ui.Heading',
  'shoutem.ui.Title',
  'shoutem.ui.Subtitle',
  'shoutem.ui.Text',
  'shoutem.ui.Caption',
];

const theme = _.merge(getTheme(), {
  ...createSharedStyle(textComponents, {
    color: 'green',
  },
});
```

Finally, some more basic customizations can be done through theme variables, you can pass custom variables when calling `getTheme`(https://github.com/shoutem/ui/blob/develop/theme.js#L55-L144).

Comment: That first code example does not work. I think it doesn't work because we merge the style after the INCLUDEs have been resolved.

Comment: No, the `getTheme` function only returns a plain object. INCLUDEs will be resolved by the `StyleProvider`. The problem in your case was that each text component usually defines its own color, because they are using theme variables. You can override properties like these by using `createSharedStyle`. I have added information on how to do that to my answer.